# Getting issue while trying to select rows in sequence via Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have table in website. Table allows to select multiple rows by pressing Shift key + Down arrow keys.

I am trying to perform same using selenium webdriver but it's not selecting rows one by one, it select row then unselect it and goes to next....

My Code :

```
List<WebElement> TRcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<TRcount.size();x++)
    {

        Actions rows = new Actions(Base.getdriver());

        rows.keyDown(TRcount.get(x),Keys.SHIFT).keyUp(TRcount.get(x+1), Keys.SHIFT).build(); 
        rows.build().perform();
        TRcount.get(x).click();

    }
```

Comment: can u share ur website link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pressing `keyDown` and `keyUp`. Try

```
Actions rows = new Actions(Base.getdriver());
rows.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
for(x = 0 ; x < TRcount.size() ; x++)
{
    TRcount.get(x).click();
}

rows.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).perform();
```

By the way, `perform()` is doing `build()`, no need to call them both.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is selecting 2 rows in sequence then deselect those 2 rows and select new 2 rows. I have 10 rows and I would like to select all rows in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be:

```
List<WebElement> TRcount = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
int x;
Actions rows = new Actions(Base.getdriver());
rows = rows.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).build(); 
for(x=0;x<TRcount.size();x++)
{
    rows = rows.sendKeys(TRcount.get(x),Keys.DOWN).build(); 
}
rows = rows.keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build(); 
rows.build().perform();
```

If you have public URL to replicate this then We could try it more easily.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help as well.